# php oop statement->execute returns boolean

Tags: php, oop

so I have the following method:

```
public function checkLogin($username){
        $sql_login=$this->dbc->prepare("SELECT username FROM credentials WHERE username=?");
        $sql_login->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt=$sql_login->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result;

    }
```

By doing a `var_dump` (and removing `$result = $stmt->get_result();`) I can see that `$stmt` is passing a boolean.

I'm new to OOP in php. I'm thinking that `get_result()` function should get the result of the `$stmt` execution.

What am I doing wrong please ?

Comment: try `$result = $sql_login->get_result();`

Comment: You are not fetching a row from the query result-set: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: Read the manual for `mysqli_stmt::execute`: *Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$result = $stmt->get_result();` converts a `mysqli::statement` object into a `mysqli::result` object, it does not return any rows from the resultset

You are also using the returned value from `$sql_login->execute();` which is in fact just a boolean instead of the  statement object called `$sql_login` in your case i.e. `$result = $sql_login->get_result();`

So you need to add something to actually fetch the row that was returned by the query, for example `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` like this

```
public function checkLogin($username){
    $sql_login=$this->dbc->prepare("SELECT username 
                                    FROM credentials 
                                    WHERE username=?");
    $sql_login->bind_param("s", $username);
    $sql_login->execute();
    $result = $sql_login->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch the row as an assoc array
    return $row;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm just getting started with PHP OOP and your explenation helped me understand where I was wrong.